# javascript regex do not followed by specific character

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to add  tag via java-script on these words for trademark symbols

```
ABC®
ABC®/MD
```

Here what I tried. The following works perfectly:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  ABC®/MD
</div>

$(".content-wrapper").each(function () {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/®\/MD/g, "<sup>®</sup>"));
}
```

However, I am not able to replace `®` without `/MD` with `<sup>` in same content-wrapper:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  ABC®/MD
</div>

$(".content-wrapper").each(function () {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/®?!\/MD/g, "<sup>®/MD</sup>"));
}
```

To sum it up, if it matches `ABC®/MD` then the result should be `ABC<sup>®/MD</sup>` and if it matches `ABC®` then the output should be `ABC<sup>®</sup>`.

Comment: `®?!\/MD` matches an optional `®` and then `!/MD`. What are you trying to do? Why don't you use your `/®\/MD/g` in the second snippet?

Comment: I am just trying to do that if it matches ABC®/MD then add ABC<sup>®/MD</sup> and if it matches ABC® then add ABC<sup>®</sup>

Comment: /®\/MD/g can't use in second snippet because it will not match ABC®

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an optional group to match 1 or 0 occurrences of `/MD` after `®` (`(?:\/MD)?`) and then you need to replace with a `$&` backreference to the whole match:

```
.replace(/®(?:\/MD)?/g, "<sup>$&</sup>")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LpfF6t/1)

JS demo:

```js
$(".content-wrapper").each(function () {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/®(?:\/MD)?/g, "<sup>$&</sup>"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  ABC®/MD and ABC®
</div>
```